# Could not cast value of type 'PFObject' to 'NSArray'

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, parse-platform

I have a Parse query that returns a set of users (PFUsers). I place them in an array so that they can be used to populate a tableView. However, when I load the tableView I get the following error message: `Could not cast value of type 'PFObject' to 'NSArray'`. Here's the relevant code (I cut out some stuff to make it easier to read). It's heavily condensed but I can create a full gist of needed.

The error is caught on the line: `self.realMatches = result as! [PFObject]`

```
import UIKit

class MatchesViewController: BaseViewController {

    var realMatches: [PFObject] = []

func loadMatches() {

        if let user = self.user {

            query{
                (results: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                if error != nil {
                    println(error)
                } else {

                    if results != nil {
                        self.matchesResults = results!
                        for result in results!{
                            if result.objectId != self.currentUser!.objectId {
                                self.realMatches = result as! [PFObject]
                            }
                        }

                        for result in results! {
                            self.user1 = result["user1"] as! PFUser
                            self.user2 = result["user2"] as! PFUser
                        }

                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            println("current user doesnt exist")
        }
    }
}

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MatchCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

let object = matchesResults[indexPath.row]

return cell
```

How can I safely store the PFUsers in an array to be used for the tableView?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`result` is a single PFObject that you have extracted from the array of `results` array using a for loop.

You should simply say

```
self.realMatches = result as! PFObject
```

but `self.realMatches` is an array, so that assignment won't work either.  You can append the result to the array using

```
self.realMatches.append(result as! PFObject)
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply! I now get an error on that line `Cannot assign a value of type 'PFObject' to a value of type [PFObject]`

Comment: So, do you want `realMatches` to be all of the results from your query?  Only the results that match the `if` statement?

Comment: Right. I might be doing this all wrong, but my query returns results and I want to place those results in the tableView. I thought the best way would be to put them in an array and then use that array later in the tableView cell function

Comment: Well, you do that with the line `self.matchesResults = results!`  What are you trying to achieve with the `for` loop?

Comment: I was using the for loop the filter out the results further. The appending definitely seemed to work. I'm getting a separate issue altogether now (table is empty, but the results array is full) but I'll investigate that further. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: You can also specify your condition in your query so that you only retrieve the required objects via a `whereKey` on your `query`